# Flutter - animation widget, trigger animation only once but get data upates on widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I came across the following problem already twice within my app:
Inside a `StatefulWidget` I have a widget that contains an animation and additionally displays other dynamic data. The animation is triggered after the animation widget has been built. However, after the animation (the drawing of a figure) has been played, I want to maintain it in the same drawn state. The rest of the dynamic data of the widget should be always rebuilt when the parent `StatefulWidget`'s `build` method is called.
Below, there is a simple example of what I try to achieve:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  MyStatefulWidget({Key key, @required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  CustomData data;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyState();
}
```

Now, I had two ideas of how to implement the state:
1) Initialize the animation widget in `initState()` and "manually" handle data updates within `didUpdateWidget()`.

```
class _MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  AnimationWidget _animationWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationWidget = AnimationWidget(displayData: widget.data);

    // starts the animation when the widget is built (?)
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _animationWidget.startAnimation());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
          children: [
          _animationWidget,
          ... // other content
          ],
          ... // column size etc.
    );
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SackenNotebookContent oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if(dataChanged(oldWidget.data, widget.data))
        setState(() {
        _animationWidget = AnimationWidget(displayData: widget.data);
        });
  }
}
```

2) To create the animation widget within the `build()` method. But then I already have doubts about when/where to trigger the animation to start. One way would be to trigger it in `didUpdateWidget()`. But again, the animation would then be triggered on every rebuild of the widget...

```
class _MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var animationWidget = AnimationWidget(displayData: widget.data);

    // but where to call animationWidget.startAnimation() ?!
    // when I call it here I get a null pointer exception...

    return Column(
          children: [
          animationWidget,
          ... // other content
          ],
          ... // column size etc.
    );
  }
}
```

Has anyone got an idea of how I could handle such a problem in flutter?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need the animation to run only once, and then on the following updates, it should only build the widget with its properties. I can see two solutions here: A `InheritedWidget` or a  `Provider`. Both of these will be able to store an arbitrary state across your Widget hierarchy.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella thank you! It actually was the time for me to integrate Provider into my app.
This way I also solved my problem :)

I made my `CustomData` extend `ChangeNotifier` and then accessed it inside the `AnimationWidget` using provider.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you can, please post a solution to your own question.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella oh I'm sorry. Actually I still have a problem:
If I have a dynamic list of `AnimationWidget` and I want to play one after the other and in certain situations I want to recreate that list with a different number of `AnimationWidget`s. I still don't know how to handle it. I am forced to initialize the animation widgets in `initState` but then I can't change the count dynamically